# Rock Paper Scissors C++ Game

Tags: c++, beginner, rock-paper-scissors

I just started to learn C++ and I decided to make a Rock Paper Scissors game. It works fine but I would like to know how can I improve it further.
In particular I couldn't find an efficient way to implement a play again feature. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

string userChoice;
int computerNumber = rand() % 3 + 1;
string computerChoice;
string userName;

if (computerNumber == 1) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerNumber == 2) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

std::cout << "Welcome to rock, paper, scissors! What is your name?" << endl;
getline(cin, userName);
std::cout << "Hello " << userName << "! What do you choose?" << endl;
getline (cin,userChoice);

for (int i=0;i<userChoice.length();i++){ 
    userChoice[i]=tolower(userChoice[i]);
}

while (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice != "scissors") {
    std::cout << "Sorry! Didn't get that. Please enter again." << endl;
    getline(cin, userChoice);
    for (int i=0;i<userChoice.length();i++){
        userChoice[i]=tolower(userChoice[i]);
    }
}


std::cout << "Press enter to continue..." << endl;
std::cin.ignore();

if(computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "rock") {
    std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "scissors") {
    std::cout << "The computer won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "paper") {
    std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "rock") {
    std::cout << "The computer won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "scissors") {
    std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "paper") {
    std::cout << "The computer won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Congrats! You won!" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Indententation

Normally code is indented between `{` and `}`

```
int main()
{
    // Start here
}
```

#### Namespace

Never Do this.

```
using namespace std;
```

If you had read any other C++ review on this board it would have told you not to do this. See: [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/14065).

There is a reason that the standard libraries are called std and not standard. Its to make prefixing them easy.

#### Rand

Though your use of `srand()` and `rand()` is perfectly valid. This version of the random number generated is now obsolete. You should look up how to use the new random number functionality provided by C++11.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14009667/14065
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666713/14065

Note:

```
int computerNumber = rand() % 3 + 1;
```

This is slightly biased against 3. Assume `RAND_MAX` is `32768`.

```
If you rolled 32768 times. Then your distribution would be.

1 10923/32768   
2 10923/32768
3 10922/32768  <- Notice this is one smaller.
```

#### Invalid:

```
} else {
    std::cout << "Congrats! You won!" << endl;
}
```

Do you really want to have an invalid choice. You have already enumerated all the valid choices. If you get to this point there is a serious error in your code. So you need to indicate this (so you can catch it in testing).

```
else
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Error");
}
```

#### Data Driven Programming

Rather than write code to decide the winner:

```
if(computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "rock") {
    std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "scissors") {
    std::cout << "The computer won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "paper") {
    std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "rock") {
    std::cout << "The computer won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "scissors") {
    std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
} else if (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "paper") {
    std::cout << "The computer won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Congrats! You won!" << endl;
}
```

Use a data structure. Assume you translate the choices into a number for each user.

```
0 -> rock
1 -> paper
2 -> scissor

// This array decides if who is the winner.
// 0 => Draw.
// 1 => Player 1
// 2 => Player 2
int winner[3][3] = {{0, 2, 1},
                    {1, 0, 2},
                    {2, 1, 0}};


// Then to decide the winner.
int theWinner = winner[player1Choice][player2Choice];
```

#### Advice

> In particular I couldn't find an efficient way to implement a play again feature.

To make things like retrying the code you need to start using functions so that you can logically compartmentalize your code.

```
int main()
{
    std::string name = getPlayerName();
    do
    {
        int player1 = getComputerMove();
        int player2 = getPlayerMove();
        displayWinner(player1, player2);
    }
    while(doesPlayerWantToContinue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! However whenever I try to create a function, I always get the error: "Control reaches end of non-void function".  How could I fix this?

Comment: This means you are function has a non void return type (ie an integer or something) and there is no `return` statement at the end of your function.